# How do I update programatically a WinForms app which is always running, deployed with msix?

Tags: winforms, uwp, desktop-bridge, msix, appinstaller

I have an app that is configured to run at startup. It doesn't have a UI, it goes to the system tray and do its stuff all day while the user is logged in.

The app should be updated automatically without the user even notice, I don't want to disturb the user. How can I do this with msix?

I have problems with AppInstaller automatic updates because the app is always running, beside it's so buggy. This code it's working to some extend. It closes the app, does the update, but it doesn't launch the app after the update. I need the app to run immediately after the update without user intervention. How can I do that?

```
                var result = await Package.Current.CheckUpdateAvailabilityAsync();
            switch (result.Availability)
            {
                case PackageUpdateAvailability.Available:
                case PackageUpdateAvailability.Required:
                    PackageManager packagemanager = new PackageManager();
                    await packagemanager.UpdatePackageAsync(new Uri("path-to-file.msix"), null, DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown);
                    break;
                case PackageUpdateAvailability.NoUpdates:
                    // Close AppInstaller.
                    MessageBox.Show("Non-updates");
                    break;
                case PackageUpdateAvailability.Unknown:
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show($"No update information associated with app");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update application silently while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216582/update-application-silently-while-running)

Comment: No, I'm using msix.

Comment: Then why does your question include the [tag:winforms] tag? If the proposed duplicate doesn't address your question, then your question seems to not be _about_ [tag:winforms] and thus should not include that tag.

Comment: @JohnG I think that would work, but in the context of msix I would have to deploy two packages, one for the "wrapper" and another package for the App or the installation would fail.
Another option i was exploring is to add a task to the Windows Task Scheduler to restart the app a few minuts after the update, but is too hacky. 
I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution supported by msix.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was in this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/non-store-developer-updates#automatically-restarting-your-app-after-an-update

Call RegisterApplicationRestart() before starting the update.

```
       private async Task UpdatePackage()
    {
        try
        {
            // Register the active instance of an application for restart in your Update method
            uint res = RelaunchHelper.RegisterApplicationRestart(null, RelaunchHelper.RestartFlags.NONE);

            PackageManager packagemanager = new PackageManager();
            await packagemanager.UpdatePackageAsync(new Uri($"path-to.msix"), null, DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in update: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }




    class RelaunchHelper
{
    #region Restart Manager Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the active instance of an application for restart.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pwzCommandLine">
    /// A pointer to a Unicode string that specifies the command-line arguments for the application when it is restarted.
    /// The maximum size of the command line that you can specify is RESTART_MAX_CMD_LINE characters. Do not include the name of the executable
    /// in the command line; this function adds it for you.
    /// If this parameter is NULL or an empty string, the previously registered command line is removed. If the argument contains spaces,
    /// use quotes around the argument.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="dwFlags">One of the options specified in RestartFlags</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// This function returns S_OK on success or one of the following error codes:
    /// E_FAIL for internal error.
    /// E_INVALIDARG if rhe specified command line is too long.
    /// </returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern uint RegisterApplicationRestart(string pwzCommandLine, RestartFlags dwFlags);
    #endregion Restart Manager Methods

    #region Restart Manager Enums
    /// <summary>
    /// Flags for the RegisterApplicationRestart function
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    internal enum RestartFlags
    {
        /// <summary>None of the options below.</summary>
        NONE = 0,

        /// <summary>Do not restart the process if it terminates due to an unhandled exception.</summary>
        RESTART_NO_CRASH = 1,
        /// <summary>Do not restart the process if it terminates due to the application not responding.</summary>
        RESTART_NO_HANG = 2,
        /// <summary>Do not restart the process if it terminates due to the installation of an update.</summary>
        RESTART_NO_PATCH = 4,
        /// <summary>Do not restart the process if the computer is restarted as the result of an update.</summary>
        RESTART_NO_REBOOT = 8
    }
    #endregion Restart Manager Enums

}
```